# Show a QMenu in response to right click in a QLabel, possible?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt4, qt5

I'm thinking in show a `QMenu` in response to user click on a `QLabel`. So I tried:

menu.h

```
#ifndef MENU_H
#define MENU_H

#include <QMenu>

class Menu : public QMenu
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Menu(QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // MENU_H
```

menu.cpp

```
#include "menu.h"

Menu::Menu(QWidget *parent) :
    QMenu(parent)
{
    addAction("Action1");
}
```

And the code who would supposedly call show the menu:

```
QLabel *label = new QLabel("...");
m_menu = new Menu;
label->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);    
connect(label, &QLabel::customContextMenuRequested, m_menu, &Menu::activateWindow);
```

But it's not working. Where I'm wrong?

Comment: Be wary of making _Labels_ interactive, as that is not their design and goes against User expectations. If the User needs to interact with the _Label_, but not necessarily edit the text, then a read only _LineEdit_ would likely be preferable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this :

menu.h

```
#ifndef MENU_H
#define MENU_H

#include <QMenu>

class Menu : public QMenu
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Menu(QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:
void showMenu(const QPoint &pos);
};

#endif // MENU_H
```

menu.cpp

```
#include "menu.h"

Menu::Menu(QWidget *parent) :
    QMenu(parent)
{
    addAction("Action1");
}
Menu::showMenu(const QPoint &pos)
{
    exec(mapToGlobal(pos));
}
```

And here your label :

```
QLabel *label = new QLabel("...");
m_menu = new Menu;
label->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);    
connect(label, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)), m_menu, SLOT(showMenu(QPoint)));
```

Comment: Great. But the menu appears at the top left corner of the screen instead of where the click happens.

Comment: Please check again, i have edit it. exec(mapToGlobal(pos));

Answer (score 0):

First, QWidget::customContextMenuRequested() and QWidget::activateWindow() have different signatures, i.e. their arguments mismatch.

Second, show QMenu using QMenu::exec() or QMenu::popup() methods rather than activateWindow().